# Sequential ant condition doesn't stop

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, ant, phpunit

I have a selenium phpunit-test and I have to start the selenium-server-standalone at first before the phpunit-test can run...
So here ist my code:

```
<target name="phpunit-no-coverage"
        unless="phpunit.done"
        depends="prepare"
        description="Run unit tests with PHPUnit (without generating code coverage reports)">
    <parallel failonany="true">
        <sequential>
            <exec executable="java">
                <arg line="-jar /var/lib/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -trustAllSSLCertificates" />
            </exec>
        </sequential>
        <sequential>
            <waitfor maxwait="1" maxwaitunit="minute">
                <socket server="localhost" port="4444" />
            </waitfor>

            <exec executable="phpunit" failonerror="true" taskname="phpunit">
                <arg value="--configuration"/>
                <arg path="${basedir}/seleniumtest.xml"/>
            </exec>


            <property name="phpunit.done" value="true"/>
        </sequential>
    </parallel>
</target>
```

I start it with jenkins and when a test fails and the build fails, everything is OK. It stops. But when everything is ok... it doesn't stop :-(
Is this the reason? `failonerror="true"`?

I think, I have to stop the selenium-server after phpunit-test. But how?

Comment: When I start the selenium-server with the server command prompt and than I start the jenkins-build without the java-condition, everything is fine.

Comment: OK.. I start the selenium-server with jenkins and not with the ant condition. that works.. but that's not what I want